# Labels and label styles not working on my form.

Tags: html, css, forms, styling

I am trying to style my form with labels and the label styles don't seem to work correctly.

Here is what my html looks like for the form:

```
 <h1 class="allpages">Questions or Concerns about Compliance Issues?</h1>
 <h3>We welcome all compliments and constructive criticism!</h3>

    <form class="webform" action="http://hsc.unm.edu/scripts/cfmailform/cfmailer.cfm" method="post">
    <!--Required hidden operators--> 
    <input name="recipient" type="hidden" value="bfloran@salud.unm.edu" />
    <input name="subject" type="hidden" value="HSC Compliance Office Email Form" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cc" value="mgwilson@salud.unm.edu" />

    <input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="http://hsc.unm.edu/admin/compliance/ThankYOU.html" /> <!-- Field validation for the user -->

 <!-- Our form in HTML -->

 <label for "name">Your Name (optional):</label>


 <br />
 <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="" /><br />
 Your E-mail (Optional):<br />
 <input name="mail" type="text" value="" />
 <br /> comment:<br /> <textarea name="comment" value="" ></textarea><br /> <br />     <input type="submit" value="Send" /> <br /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></div>
```

My css for this part looks like this:

```
 .allpages {text-align:center;color:#007a86;}
 h3{text-align:center;}
 .webform {background-color: #eeeeee; 
 width: 655px;  border: solid;
  border-color: #e9e9e9;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 15px 0px 15px   17px;}
.webform .label {display:inline-block; width:200px; vertical-align:top; text-align:right;}
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior and what is actually happening?

Comment: What does "not working" mean. Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mt4jK/

Comment: well I wanted the actual label: (Your Name (optional): ) on the left side, with the form part on the right instead of the label on top and the form part underneath.  thanks!

Comment: Thanks. After looking at your fiddle, my answer is what you want, but it is hard to see what your intended result is because there are so many invalid images disrupting the layout.

Comment: I used .webform .label.  Isn't that the correct css to use?

Comment: I took out some of top part of the form: here it is again: http://jsfiddle.net/mt4jK/

Comment: I fixed your fiddle in my answer.

Comment: oh I figured it out.  I needed css for the textarea part as well..thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `label` is not a *class*... it is a *tag*.

Working CSS for that piece:

```
.webform label { } /* see .label changed to label */
```

**Also:** Your elements were not laid out properly in HTML, some were not even labels.

---

### **Fixed fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/mt4jK/2/

---

**Excerpt:**

```
.webform label {
    width:200px;
   vertical-align:top;
    text-align:right;
    float: left
}

<label for="name">Your Name (optional):</label>
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks digitalextremist.  It kind of did, but the comment box still isn't aligned for me for some reason even after using the code you suggested.  I think it might be because of the textarea tag I used.  I tried it again however and it looked fine on the fiddle, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Yes, the `textarea` is different than the `input` tags, so you may want to adjust your tactic for that sort of tag.

Answer (score 0):

You created a class selector to reference some tag with class=label